# How to change Bloclkchain.info ticker api?

Tags: php, laravel, blockchain

i want to integrate blockchain in my web i have developed it from a developer . problemm is blockchain is converting entered amount into usd. mean if i want to deposit 0.001 btc on my web account it shows 0.00000006btc mean price of 0.001 usd. please tell how to solve issue that it show amount in btc and don't convert it into usd. my Blockchain preivew code is listed below.

```
public function btcPreview(Request $request)
    {
        $data['amount'] = $request->amount;
        $data['charge'] = $request->charge;
        $data['transaction_id'] = $request->transaction_id;
        $pay = Payment::first();
        $tran = FundLog::whereTransaction_id($data['transaction_id'])->first();

        $blockchain_root = "https://blockchain.info/";
        $blockchain_receive_root = "https://api.blockchain.info/";
        $mysite_root = url('/');
        $secret = "ABIR";
        $my_xpub = $pay->btc_xpub;
        $my_api_key = $pay->btc_api;
        $am = $data['amount'];
        $invoice_id = $tran->transaction_id;

        $callback_url = route('btc_ipn',['invoice_id'=>$invoice_id,'secret'=>$secret]);



        if ($tran->btc_acc == null){

                $resp = file_get_contents($blockchain_receive_root . "v2/receive?key=" . $my_api_key . '&callback=' . urlencode($callback_url) . '&xpub=' . $my_xpub);

                $response = json_decode($resp);

                $sendto = $response->address;

            if ($sendto!="") {
                $api = "https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=USD&value=".$data['amount'];
                $usd = file_get_contents($api);
                $tran->btc_amo = $usd;
                $tran->btc_acc = $sendto;
                $tran->save();
            }else{
                session()->flash('message', "SOME ISSUE WITH API");
                Session::flash('type', 'warning');
                return redirect()->back();
            }
        }else{
            $usd = $tran->btc_amo;
            $sendto = $tran->btc_acc;
        }
        /*$sendto = "1HoPiJqnHoqwM8NthJu86hhADR5oWN8qG7";
        $usd =100;*/

        /*if ($tran->btc_acc == null){

            if (file_exists($blockchain_receive_root . "v2/receive?key=" . $my_api_key . '&callback=' . urlencode($callback_url) . '&xpub=' . $my_xpub)) {
                $resp = file_get_contents($blockchain_receive_root . "v2/receive?key=" . $my_api_key . '&callback=' . urlencode($callback_url) . '&xpub=' . $my_xpub);

                $response = json_decode($resp);

                $sendto = $response->address;

                $api = "https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=USD&value=".$data['amount'];

                $usd = file_get_contents($api);

                $tran->btc_amo = $usd;
                $tran->btc_acc = $sendto;
                $tran->save();
            }else{
                session()->flash('message', 'BlockChain API or XPUB not Correct.');
                Session::flash('type', 'warning');
                Session::flash('title', 'Opps');
                return redirect()->back();
            }
        }else{
            $usd = $tran->btc_amo;
            $sendto = $tran->btc_acc;
        }*/
        /*$sendto = "1HoPiJqnHoqwM8NthJu86hhADR5oWN8qG7";
        $usd =100;*/
        $var = "bitcoin:$sendto?amount=$usd";
        $data['code'] =  "<img src=\"https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chl=$var&choe=UTF-8\" title='' style='width:300px;' />";
        $data['general'] = GeneralSetting::first();
        $data['site_title'] = $data['general']->title;
        $data['basic'] = BasicSetting::first();
        $data['page_title'] = "BTC Send Preview";
        $data['payment_type'] = 3;
        $data['payment'] = Payment::first();
        $data['btc'] = $usd;

        $data['add'] = $sendto;
        $data['fund'] = $tran;
        return view('user.btc-send',$data);
    }
```